# Saving to the Database while keeping the UI responsive VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, multithreading, methods, freeze

I have a button that saves some Textboxes & Datagridview content to the database using many methods, so the whole process take a long time and UI freezes for many seconds, how can I avoid that ? Maybe using multithreading, I've done my research but I still can't figure it out. Here is my code to understand me better :

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

Dim NbrP As Integer = CInt(combobox1.SelectedIndex)
    Select Case NBR
        Case 0
            Try
                SubmitA(...)
                SubmitB(...)
            MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error :" & ex.ToString())
            End Try
        Case 1
            Try
                SubmitA(...)
                SubmitB(...)
                SubmitC(...)
                SubmitD(...)
            MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error :" & ex.ToString())
            End Try
         ..
         ..

    End Select
End Sub
```

This is an example of one of the methods used in the Select Case :

```
Public Sub SubmitA(ByVal txtSupT As TextBox, ByVal cmbIntP As ComboBox, ByVal lblRecupIdF As Label)
    Dim cmdSau = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO sau (sup_totale, nbr_parcelles, ferme_id_ferme) VALUES (@suptot, @nbrparcelles, @fermeid)", db_con)
    Dim cmdRecupIdSau = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id_sau FROM sau WHERE id_sau = ( SELECT MAX(id_sau) FROM sau)", db_con)
    Dim drRecSAU As MySqlDataReader

    cmdSau.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suptot", CDbl(txtSupT.Text))
    cmdSau.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nbrparcelles", CInt(cmbIntP.Text))
    cmdSau.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fermeid", CInt(lblRecupIdF.Text))
    cmdSau.ExecuteNonQuery()

    drRecSAU = cmdRecupIdSau.ExecuteReader()
    While drRecSAU.Read
        recupIdSAU = CInt(drRecSAU(0))
    End While
    drRecSAU.Close()
End Sub
```

As you can see, if the combobox1 value is 0, the Case One get executed, and if it's 1, the Case Two get executed.. But the Case Two execute the Case One methods + other methods, so it get even heavier to save the data.

I just want to show a CircularProgressBar near the BtnSave while keeping the UI responsive and waiting for for the whole data to be saved.

Thank you in advance, I'm sorry if it's a little unclear, I tried to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: As far as I know, you really can't do it without threading. The simplest way I've found is to use BackgroundWorker. In your case, I would save (to an array, or collection of some sort) the data to be INSERTed, and then pass that to the background worker. You can even use BackgroundWorker's progress reporting functionality to update the UI as the process executes.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Might I suggest store procedure. Using MAX to get the unique ID doesn't guarantee you will receive the one from your last insert. Look at LAST_INSERT_ID (as long as it's in the same transaction) and SP will limit the number of queries you make.

Comment: @the_lotus, nice catch, but now that you draw my attention to it...what is the point of that query. Even ignoring the existence of `last_insert_id()`, that query could just be `SELECT MAX(id_sau) FROM sau`. There is no need for it to be a subquery in a WHERE that I can see.

Comment: @Uueerdo I've red that query too fast. You are right, the where clause is useless in that case.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, your answers were really helpful, I appricate it ! I still wonder if it's possible to make the UI responsive during the operation if I encounter some sort of freezes later. (After fixing the issues you mentioned, without changing too much my code and saving the data to an array, or collection.. using the BGworker)

Answer (score 0):

First figure out why it's taking a long time. Are you doing many updates? Does each individual update take a long time?

Use the MySQL EXPLAIN command to see what your queries are really doing. There may be inefficiencies that could be fixed by adding new indexes or restructuring the queries. Check for unnecessary JOINs or other unnecessary work.

For example, in your post you have the query:

```
SELECT id_sau FROM sau WHERE id_sau = ( SELECT MAX(id_sau) FROM sau)", db_con)
```

Why not just:

```
select max(id_sau) from sau
```

?

why find the max value ... and then search the table looking for the value that you've already found?

If you have many separate calls to the database, you may be able to improve performance by combining them into one call. Put multiple SQL statements in a single call, or write a sproc.

If you have many inserts of the same record, you can probably improve performance by making one big insert that puts in many records, rather than executing the same insert many times. (There are many technical issues on this, so it will depend how many record you're inserting.)